# Silent install of .msu windows updates?

Tags: c#, windows, installation, updates, silent

I am encountering small problem with windows updates silent install.
Why I need it? I have bit copy of system disk which I am using for reinstall win7(with advantage of .net framework, visual studio, java and 50+ another apps installed in once).
Then I need install some important update. I coded small utillity in c#, working OK except
install is not silent even using  `startInfo.Arguments = "/quiet/norestart/passive";`. 
Not silent : I mean  there are at least two windows like asking if I need install or reboot options in end.

Problem is spoken in another forum [How are people deploying HOTFIXES .msu files?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/configmgrswdist/thread/5a4a4dc7-845a-41d5-8694-95c3da38578f)
but solution is a bit not clear for me. Does somebody know any way how fix it?
Again, `startInfo.Arguments = "/quiet/norestart/passive";`  or `startInfo.Arguments = @"/qb!"+ "REBOOT=ReallySuppress"+ @"/qn";`  are not working and in link is explained why.
`textBox1.Text` is location af all hotfixes and updates in one directory.

{

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text);
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        //startInfo.Arguments = "/quiet/norestart/passive";

        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            label1.Text = "Working";
            startInfo.FileName = filePaths[i];
            startInfo.Arguments = @"/qb!"+ "REBOOT=ReallySuppress"+ @"/qn";

            try
            {
                Process.Start(startInfo.FileName).WaitForExit(); 

            }
               catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
        label1.Text = " Done ";

        }
```

Comment: Why are you using verbatim string literals where none are needed? `/` isn't an escape character in C#.

Answer (score 1):

For a start you're just chaining together the arguments without spaces and thus are only passing a single argument that likely won't work. Try

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/qb! REBOOT=ReallySuppress /qn"
```

Comment: i did it and another 10+ formats. Problem is not in arguments, else startInfo.Arguments = "/quiet/norestart/passive" is enough. See link above.

Comment: OK I tried and nothing changed - wuse still asking install? reboot? etc.

Comment: But "/quiet/norestart/passive" will not work, MS apps pretty much always need spaces between switches i.e. "/quiet /norestart /passive"

Comment: Yes, true, my mistake but in this way still not working.  I have still windows asking user for input.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I bypassed it using pure CMD line. Silent install without windows except exceptions.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text);
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) { label1.Text = "Working On first task"; }
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + "@" + "\"" + filePaths[i] + "\"" + " /quiet /norestart";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            label1.Text = (100 * i / filePaths.Length).ToString() + " % is done"; 

        }
        label1.Text = "Done";

    }
```